# How to proof scaling property of dirac delta function using measure theory?

Tags: measure-theory, dirac-delta

following the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Scaling_and_symmetry) of the dirac delta function I have the following question.

If we consider the dirac delta function as a measure (as it is described in the article) how can we proof the scaling property?

It seems to me that for a measure we have $\delta({A}) = \mathbb{1}_A(0)$ and thus $\delta(A) = \delta(kA)\neq \frac{1}{|k|}\delta(A) $

how to reconcile it with the proof (also in wiki article) that uses the substitution rule?

Comment: You are correct that as a measure, one has $\delta(A)=1_A(0)$. But the scaling property from Wikipedia does not apply to $\delta(kA)$, but rather to $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(k x)dx$$
where the substitution rule can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the definition of "$\delta(ax)$" in Wikipedia should rather be understood as a change of variable (i.e. a composition) for distributions, which is aimed to extend the behavior of functions, so that one can manipulate $\delta(ax)$ as if it was a function.

Let me define for a function $g$ (for example continuous), $m_ag(x) := g(ax)$. Then for any test function $\varphi$ smooth and compactly supported (but continuous and compactly supported is enough)
$$
\int_{\Bbb R^d} m_ag(x)\,\varphi(x)\,\mathrm d x = \frac{1}{|a|^d} \int_{\Bbb R^d} g(x)\,\varphi(x/a)\,\mathrm d x.
$$
Therefore, if $f$ is a distribution on $\Bbb R^d$, one ***defines*** $m_af$ as the distribution such that for any test function $\varphi$,
$$
\langle m_af, \varphi\rangle = \frac{1}{|a|^d}\,\langle f, m_{1/a}\varphi\rangle,
$$
where $\langle f, \varphi\rangle$ denotes the action of $f$ on $\varphi$. In particular this applies to measures since they can be seen as distributions of order $0$ by Riesz's representation theorem. For the particular case of the Dirac delta $\delta=\delta_0$ which verifies
$$
\langle\delta,\varphi\rangle = \int_{\Bbb R^d} \varphi(x)\,\delta(\mathrm d x) = \varphi(0)
$$
it gives
$$
\langle m_a\delta, \varphi\rangle = \frac{1}{|a|^d}\,\langle \delta, m_{1/a}\varphi\rangle = \frac{1}{|a|^d}\,m_{1/a}\varphi(0) = \frac{1}{|a|^d}\,\varphi(0) = \frac{1}{|a|^d}\,\langle \delta, \varphi\rangle
$$
that is $m_a\delta = \frac{1}{|a|^d}\,\delta$ (your case being the case $d=1$ in dimenion $1$).

---

This is indeed not a natural operation to perform on sets. If we want to work only on measures acting on sets, then this is equivalent to say that for a measure $\mu$ we decided to define
$$
m_a\mu(A) = \frac{1}{|a|^d}\int_{\Bbb R^d} \Bbb 1_{A}(x/a)\,\mu(\mathrm d x) = \frac{1}{|a|^d}\int_{\Bbb R^d} \Bbb 1_{aA}(x)\,\mu(\mathrm d x) = \frac{1}{|a|^d}\,\mu(aA)
$$
with the notation $aA = \{x\in\Bbb R^d: x/a\in A\}$. So to summarize, to be compatible with the behavior of functions, it is better to define "$\mu(ax)$" as
$$
m_a\mu(A) = \frac{1}{|a|^d}\,\mu(aA).
$$

Comment: I am not familiar with the theory of distributions (tod) so I hoped to arrive at the property without relying on it. It may not be possible. In the bellow Paragraph I guess your definition is:

$$m_a\mu(A) := \frac{1}{|a|^d}\int_{\Bbb R^d} \Bbb 1_{A}(x/a)\,\mu(\mathrm d x) $$

correct?

If so: 
either you are defining the operator based on the intuition from the tod or your definition is basically s.t. the scaling property holds.

Both seem unsatisfactory for me. I am looking for a definition that is purely measure theoretic driven... but maybe I just have to work through tod

Comment: Yes, that's the point of what is written above, the intuition comes from the identification distributions = generalized functions.
But as another formal point of view, without distributions, you can say that you want to generalize the case when $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure, that is make the identification $\mu(\mathrm d x)$ with $f(x)$ if $\mu(\mathrm d x) = f(x)\,\mathrm d x$. Then you can see that the $|a|^d$ comes from the $\mathrm d x$. Very formally
$$
"\mu(ax)" := f(ax) = \frac{\mu(a\,\mathrm d x)}{|a|^d\,\mathrm d x}
$$